# How to get the default $id from another table using laravel model relationship?

Tags: sql, laravel

I am facing the problem whereby I don't know the syntax of letting the id of my property model equals to property_id value in property_doc table.

In PropertyDoc model

```
public function property()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Properties::class, 'property_id');
}
```

In Properties model

```
public function property_id()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PropertyDoc::class, 'property_id');
}
```

In PropertyController

```
public function StoreInfoProperty(Request $request)
{
    $propertyInfo = new PropertyDoc;
    $propertyInfo->property_id = $property_id;
}
```

I am stuck at retrieving the default `id` value in `properties` database to be equal to the `property_id` in `property_docs` database. Thank you.

Comment: For additional clarity, could you add your table migration files?

Comment: is `property_id` is the primary key of `Properties` model ?

Comment: nope, property_id is the foreign key of PropertyDoc model.

Comment: Schema::create('property_docs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('property_id')->constrained('properties');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Answer (score 0):

You should change the naming of the relationship, see my example below:

In Properties model

```
public function propertyDocs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PropertyDoc::class, 'property_id', 'id');
}
```

In PropertyDoc model

```
public function property()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Properties::class, 'property_id', 'id');
}
```

In controller

```
public function StoreInfoProperty(Request $request)
{
    $propertyDoc = PropertyDoc::with(['property'])->where('...logic here');

    $property_id = $propertyDoc->property->id;

}
```

hope can help you and happy coding !

Comment: thanks but just to clarify, the id variable is the auto-increment id of properties. Is the method still the same as the above?

Comment: that's right, you don't need to worry too much about the ID